# How to change the values in a column for all the rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, user-defined-functions

I have a data frame with a column name "Class". 
The column class contains 5 integer values.

```
> df <- read.csv("CancerData.csv")
> unique(df$Class)
[1] 1 5 2 4 3
```

I want to alter the values in Class column in such a way that, for all the rows in data frame, the Class values larger than 3 should be set back to 3. So the end result should look as below.

```
 > unique(df$Class)
    [1] 1 2 3
```

I have written a function to execute that.

```
myFunction <- function() 
{
  for( i in row.names(df$Class))
  {
    if ( df$Class > 3)
    {
      df$Class = 3
    }
  }

}
myFunction()
```

But the Class column still remains unchanged.

My question is how to change the values in df$Class with the condition mentioned in the myFunction() ?

Comment: you could simply use df[df$Class > 3,]$Class = 3

Comment: I think it is better to loop through the sequence of rows in the for loop. 2) the `i` is not used inside the loop, i.e `for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {if(df$Class[i] > 3) df$Class[i] <- 3}} df}`

Comment: `df$Class[df$Class > 3] <- 3` will do it, no need for a loop.

Comment: `df$Class <- pmin(3, df$Class)`

Comment: df[df$Class > 3,]$Class = 3 and df$Class[df$Class > 3] <- 3 both worked perfectly. Thank you all for replying.